# Android Studio 4.1 debugger break points not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, debugging, android-studio-4.1

After updating my android studio from version 4.0 to 4.1 the debugger break points don't work anymore:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 17):

I had to rollback. No one has time for this sh**...

1. Uninstall Android Studio
2. Reboot
3. Download & Install AS 4.0.2: https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/4.0.2.0/android-studio-ide-193.6821437-windows.exe or https://developer.android.com/studio/archive
4. Change Gradle classpath to 4.0.2 in build.gradle

All better now...

Comment: First time updating AS in 2 years. A bunch of bugs, never again....

Answer (score 3):

I would try the following:

- Try the 'attach debugger' option with the app running, via the button on the toolbar, or finding the action (cmd/ctrl shift + a and type 'attach debugger to android process').
- Make sure that `debuggable true` is set in your module/build.gradle for the flavor you are currently using, (Check the build variants tab).
- Be sure that the Android Gradle Plugin points to the same version that Android Studio has, this is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0` for Android Studio 4.1.
- Clear data, uninstall the app, and run 'Invalidate Caches & restart' from Android Studio.
- Make sure you don't have the stable and the canary versions of A.S running (I faced debugger issues in the past because of that).
- Restart adb? (`adb kill-server && adb start-server`).
- Reboot / Switch the emulator / device?.
- Reboot the computer?.
- If all of the above fails, I would also try this script: https://github.com/rock3r/deep-clean

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been running into these troubles with 4.1 too. The only thing that seems to work consistently is the ``Debug app`` button (i.e. rerun the app with debugging enabled) - attach to debugger`` connects but just seems to ignore breakpoints half the time

Comment: Thank you for the provided solutions. i tried but non of them worked, i had to change  build.gradle`minifyEnabled false` && `shrinkResources false` in buildType debug.

Comment: I'm in the same situation the interruption points don't work

Comment: It's a relief to know that placing breakpoints in 4.1 starts with a 9-step troubleshooting process.

Answer (score 1):

In  my case it only happens when debugging on the emulator. Debugging on a real device or unit tests works.

Answer (score 1):

Restart ADB in menú dispositives Android Studio

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### I'm using Android Studio 4.1. Following steps worked for me.

- delete the .gradle folder in /.gradle
- clean the project using Build > clean project
- rebuild the project using Build > Rebuild project

Now try to debug the code.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added

```
debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

in buildTypes of app level gradle.
I just removed this and then I am able to debug. That's it.